# Filter Criteria to filter out cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to get a filter criteria in order to filter out all blanks from a list that is ever changing. I have a list being driven by if statements and at any given time most of it is zeros. Here is the table:

`Item Number  ||  Description
 0                0
 179-0001         RC-5019
 0                0
 179-0030         SS304V Braid
 0                0
 0                0`

I've tried to do an advance filter with this and the list of Materials that I have but it keeps coming up with the error "The extract range has a missing or invalid field name. So obviously I'm doing something wrong.

I want the final table to look like

`Item Number   ||   Description
 179-0001            RC-5019
 179-0030            SS304V Braid`

Comment: Could you just add filters to the columns you want an exclude the blanks?

Comment: @Jacob I could but I want it to print out to a different Table